# Heap based priority queue implementation

Tags: java, oop, binary-tree, heap, priority-queue

I've made a priority queue implementation that uses heap, but it works somewhat but I've encountered a problem where if I dequeue the priority queue it doesn't heapify correctly.
For example if I input 10 elements from an array ranging from 0 - 9, since this is a MaxHeap implementation it should always return the highest value and then heapify to correct the tree but it doesn't.

When I dequeue and get 9 and I don't get 8 when I dequeue again, I instead get 0 because it swaps from the last index but it doesn't fix the tree.
I've tried debugging and unit testing but I simply can't find where the problem is. I was wondering if some fresh eyes could see what I could not, thanks in advance!

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class HeapPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements PriorityQueue<T> {
    
    private Class<T> clazz;
    private int lastIndex, capacity;
    private T heap[];
    
    public HeapPriorityQueue(Class<T> clazz, int capacity) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.heap = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, capacity);
        this.lastIndex = -1;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.lastIndex = -1;
        this.heap = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, capacity);
        System.out.println("The queue has been destroyed!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lastIndex == -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFull() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lastIndex == capacity-1;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lastIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(T element) {
        if (!isFull()) {
            heap[++lastIndex] = element;
            shiftUp();
            
            String test = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < heap.length; i++) {
                test += "" + heap[i] + " ";
            }
            System.out.println(test);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T dequeue() {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new QueueEmptyException();
        T rootValue = heap[0];
        swap(0, lastIndex);
        heap[lastIndex] = null;
        lastIndex--;
        shiftDown();
        String test = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < heap.length; i++) {
            test += "" + heap[i] + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(test);
        return rootValue;
    }

    @Override
    public T getFront() {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new QueueEmptyException();
        return heap[0];
    }
    
    private void shiftUp() {
        int index = lastIndex;
        int parentIndex = parent(index);
        while (parentIndex > -1 && heap[index].compareTo(heap[parentIndex]) > 0) {
            swap(index, parentIndex);
            index = parentIndex;
            parentIndex = parent(parentIndex);
        }
    }
    
    private void shiftDown() {
        int index = 0;
        
        while (index < lastIndex) {
            
            T maxValue = heap[index];
            int maxIndex = index;
            
            int leftIndex = left(index);
            if (leftIndex > 0 && maxValue.compareTo(heap[leftIndex]) > 0) {
                maxValue = heap[leftIndex];
                maxIndex = leftIndex;
            }
            
            int rightIndex = left(index);
            if (rightIndex > 0 && maxValue.compareTo(heap[rightIndex]) > 0) {
                maxValue = heap[rightIndex];
                maxIndex = rightIndex;
            }
            
            if (maxIndex == index) {
                break;
            }
            
            swap(maxIndex, index);
            index = maxIndex;
        }
    }
    
    private int parent(int index) {
        return index/2;
    }
    
    private int left(int index) {
        int leftChild = index * 2;
        return leftChild;
    }

    private int right(int index) {
        int rightChild = index * 2 + 1;
        return rightChild;
    }
    
    private void swap(int index1, int index2) {
        T temp = heap[index1];
        heap[index1] = heap[index2];
        heap[index2 ] = temp;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] data = {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 20};
        HeapPriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new HeapPriorityQueue<Integer>(Integer.class,10);
        for (Integer i : data) {
            pq.enqueue(i);
        }
        System.out.println(pq.dequeue());
        System.out.println(pq.dequeue());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Could you be a more specific "if I dequeue the priority queue it doesn't heapify correctly."?

Comment: @Progman I've explained it better now, sorry for not explaining well earlier.

Comment: `PriorityQueue` is class and you cannot `implement` it. Are you sure you gave a **compilable** code?

Comment: PriorityQueue It is probably OP' own interface

Comment: Yes I'm using another interface, I'm not using the PriorityQueue from the Java class library.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik The code compiles correctly it's just that the elements are not in correct order, I'm wondering where the fault is. I'm implementing my own interface btw, thanks in advance!